# In Corona SDK, how can I put a restart function at the end of my game?

Tags: lua, cross-platform, coronasdk

I have already made a restart button, but I don't know how to attach a restart function to the button.  If anyone could help, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local widget = require("widget")
local function Restart(event)
    if "began" == event.phase then
        --code here when touch begin
    elseif "moved" == event.phase then
        --code here when  move
    elseif "ended" == event.phase or "cancelled" == event.phase then
        --code here when touch end
    end
end

-- Create the widget
local button1 = widget.newButton{
    left = 100,
    top = 200,
    id = "button1",
    label = "Label",
    onEvent = Restart
}
```

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html
You can have a look at it.

By the way, when restart your game don't forget init Variables & display.* (like display.newGroup() / display.newImage() etc.)